# Alliance VHDL toolchain, Error 18 illegal concurrent statement

Tags: vhdl

When attempting to simulate the following, I'm receiving the aforementioned error.

**Source**

```
    library IEEE;
        use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
        use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
        use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

    entity AAM is
      generic(
        constant MEMORY_WIDTH : integer :=   7;
        constant MEMORY_SIZE  : integer := 255
      );

      port(
        CLOCK         :  in std_ulogic;

        EVENT_DATA    : out std_ulogic_vector( MEMORY_WIDTH downto 0 );
        EVENT_ADDRESS : out std_ulogic_vector( MEMORY_WIDTH downto 0 );

        READ_DATA     : out std_ulogic_vector( MEMORY_WIDTH downto 0 );
        READ_ADDRESS  :  in std_ulogic_vector( MEMORY_WIDTH downto 0 );
        READ_STATUS   : out std_ulogic;

        WRITE_DATA    :  in std_ulogic_vector( MEMORY_WIDTH downto 0 );
        WRITE_ADDRESS :  in std_ulogic_vector( MEMORY_WIDTH downto 0 );
        WRITE_STATUS  : out std_ulogic
      );
    end AAM;

architecture dataflow of AAM is
  subtype WORD is std_ulogic_vector( MEMORY_WIDTH downto 0 );
  type CACHE is array ( MEMORY_SIZE downto 0 ) of WORD;
  signal MEMORY : CACHE;
begin
  process( CLOCK )
  begin
    if ( falling_edge(CLOCK) ) then
        READ_DATA <= MEMORY( conv_integer( READ_ADDRESS ) );

        READ_STATUS  <= '1';
        WRITE_STATUS <= '0';
    else
        MEMORY( conv_integer( WRITE_ADDRESS ) ) <= WRITE_DATA;

        EVENT_DATA    <= WRITE_DATA;
        EVENT_ADDRESS <= WRITE_ADDRESS;

        READ_STATUS  <= '0';
        WRITE_STATUS <= '1';
    end if;
  end process;
end dataflow;
```

**Build**

> vasy -Vao design
>
> genpat design
>
> asimut -b design design design_out

**Output**

> ```
>          @        @@@@ @     @                            @@@@@@@@@@ 
>          @       @    @@    @@@                           @   @@   @ 
>         @@@     @@     @     @                           @    @@    @
>         @@@     @@@              @@@ @@ @@@   @@@  @@@@       @@     
>        @  @@     @@@@     @@@@    @@@ @@  @@   @@    @@       @@     
>        @  @@       @@@@     @@    @@  @@  @@   @@    @@       @@     
>       @    @@        @@@    @@    @@  @@  @@   @@    @@       @@     
>       @@@@@@@   @      @@   @@    @@  @@  @@   @@    @@       @@     
>      @      @@  @@     @@   @@    @@  @@  @@   @@    @@       @@     
>      @      @@  @@@    @    @@    @@  @@  @@   @@   @@@       @@     
>    @@@@    @@@@ @  @@@@   @@@@@@ @@@@ @@@ @@@   @@@@  @@    @@@@@@   
>
>                             A SIMUlation Tool
>
>              Alliance CAD System 5.0,          asimut v3.02
>              Copyright (c) 1991...1999-2016, ASIM/LIP6/UPMC
>              E-mail        :    alliance-users@asim.lip6.fr
>
>     Paris, France, Europe, Earth, Solar system, Milky Way, ...
> ```
>
> initializing ... searching `design` ... BEH : Compiling `design.vbe`
>   (Behaviour) ... `design.vbe` Error line 3438 : syntax error
>   `design.vbe` Error 18 line 3438 :illegal concurrent statement
>
> ```
>     cannot continue further more.
>
>             have a nice day...
> ```

The alliance tool-chain has been a bitch to work with so far, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Note: I've not included the design.c/pattern source as the VBE file is failing and generated from the first stage `vasy -Vao design`. Yet the error is not reported until the final stage.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible for someone knowledgeable of VHDL to comment without a little context around your single if statement (which is a sequential statement). Perhaps you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Searching the error statement it is found in the routine vbl_error() in vbl_utils.c. Searching for a call to vbl_error (18 reveals it's in vbl_bcomp_y.y, the rule for concurrent_statement . The implication appears to be that you are trying to use a sequential statement (your if statement) in a place where a concurrent statement is expected (an architecture body). Provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Make an [MCVE] of this source. Compile it in some other VHDL tools to see if they give a more useful error message. The error message is entirely correct, of course - this IS an illegal statement in a concurrent region, but what that means depends on the context around this statement, which you haven't supplied.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Works fine with GHDL.

Comment: Works and it's legal VHDL, but it's unlikely to be synthesisable because of its (not properly explicit) use of both clock edges. Restrict yourself to the normal patterns of synthesisable VHDL.

Comment: Not valid in ghdl, no declared overload for function conv_integer with a parameter of std_ulogic_vector in Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned. Prior to -2008 std_ulogic_vector was a distinct type declaration for std_logic_vector, while in -2008 std_logic_vector is a resolved subtype of std_ulogic_vector. Alliance was not -2008 compliant. There is no illegal concurrent statement in the supposed [mcve].