# VHDL 8x16 Register-FIle not synthesizable

Tags: vhdl, cpu-registers, synthesis

I have to write a 8x16 bit Register-file for a project during my Semester.
And we have to run the VHDL synthesis after writing this module.

But i get these Error:

```sh
Error line 26 : syntax error
vbl_bcomp_y.y 4464 : Error 18 line 26 in file regfile :illegal concurrent statement
Note that errors might also be due to unsupported statements
```

Here my code to do the synthesis with `vasy`

```vhdl
-- ...

architecture RTL of REGFILE is
  type t_regfile is array (0 to 7) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal reg : t_regfile := (others => X"0000"); -- Init with 0
begin
  process (clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      if load_lo = '1' then
        -- The error line 
        reg (to_integer(unsigned(in_sel))) (7 downto 0) <= in_data (7 downto 0);
      end if;
      if (load_hi = '1') then
        reg (to_integer (unsigned (in_sel))) (15 downto 8) <= in_data (15 downto 8);
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  process (out0_sel, out1_sel, reg)
  begin
    out0_data <= reg (to_integer(unsigned(out0_sel)));
    out1_data <= reg (to_integer (unsigned(out1_sel)));
  end process;
end RTL;
```

Can anybody describe how to fix this synthesis error ?

Comment: Your code is not complete (no entity or package includes) nor do you indicate which is line is line 26. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Most likely it's the numeric_std package missing. Needed for e.g. to_integer function in your line of error. This is a guess until a reproducable example is provided.

Comment: See [Alliance VHDL toolchain, Error 18 illegal concurrent statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41072435/alliance-vhdl-toolchain-error-18-illegal-concurrent-statement) producing the same error when no visible declaration for the function conv_integer was found with a parameter type of std_ulogic_vector which doesn't share a base type with std_logic_vector in -1993 package std_logic_1164 for the declaration of conv_integer in Synopsys package std_logic_unsigned.  Asimut can't find a function to_integer which likely says you used std_logic_arith instead of numeric_std. Provide a [mcve].